# AssertionError: incompatible sizes: argument 'height' must be length 5 or scalar

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a json file which i am sorting in reverse using natsort and then i want to plot a graph of the "Speed" but i am getting an error. I have now included the JSON file here as well.

```
"AssertionError: incompatible sizes: argument 'height' must be length 5 or scalar"

Traceback (most recent call last): File "new.py", line 71, in <module> visualize_type(sorted_waypoints) File "new.py", line 45, in visualize_type plt.bar(xlocations, counter.values()) File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matp‌​lotlib/pyplot.py", line 2515, in bar ret = ax.bar(left, height, width=width, bottom=bottom, **kwargs) File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matp‌​lotlib/axes.py", line 4999, in bar nbars)
```

Code:

```
import json
import datetime
import pprint
from operator import itemgetter
import natsort
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter



#path to gps data file in json format.
data_file = "waypoints.json"


def speed_ans(self, data_file):
    pass



def visualize_type(output):
    """Visualize data by category in a bar graph"""

    #This returns a dict where it sums the total per Category.
    counter = Counter(item["Speed"] for item in output)

    # Set the labels which are based on the keys of our counter.
    labels = tuple("Speed")

    # Set where the labels hit the x-axis
    xlocations = np.arange(len(labels)) + 0.5

    # Width of each bar
    width = 0.5

    # Assign data to a bar plot
    plt.bar(xlocations, counter.values(), width=width)

    # Assign labels and tick location to x- and y-axis
    plt.xticks(xlocations + width / 2, labels, rotation=90)
    plt.yticks(range(0, max(counter.values()), 5))

    # Give some more room so the labels aren't cut off in the graph
    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.4)

    # Make the overall graph/figure larger
    plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 12, 8

    # Save the graph!
    plt.savefig("Graph.png")

    plt.clf()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(data_file) as f:
        waypoints = json.load(f)

    sorted_waypoints = natsort.natsorted(waypoints, key=itemgetter(*['Speed']), reverse = True)
    pprint.pprint(sorted_waypoints)

    visualize_type(sorted_waypoints)
```

waypoints.json file :

```
[{
    "Latitude": 1.282143333,
    "Timestamp": 1434368770,
    "Speed": 7.696,
    "Longitude": 103.850785
}, {
    "Latitude": 1.282205,
    "Timestamp": 1434368771,
    "Speed": 7.233,
    "Longitude": 103.850806667
}, {
    "Latitude": 1.282205,
    "Timestamp": 1434368772,
    "Speed": 7.233,
    "Longitude": 103.850806667
}, {
    "Latitude": 1.282205,
    "Timestamp": 1434368773,
    "Speed": 7.444,
    "Longitude": 103.850806667
}, {
    "Latitude": 1.282261667,
    "Timestamp": 1434368774,
    "Speed": 6.933,
    "Longitude": 103.850833333
}]
```

Comment: Could you please provide the whole Traceback of the AssertionError?

Comment: @MSeifert Yeah sure.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new.py", line 71, in <module>
    visualize_type(sorted_waypoints)
  File "new.py", line 45, in visualize_type
    plt.bar(xlocations, counter.values())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2515, in bar
    ret = ax.bar(left, height, width=width, bottom=bottom, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/axes.py", line 4999, in bar
    nbars)

Comment: Please edit your answer adding the traceback to make it more readable. Thanks.

Comment: Alright will do that.

Comment: What is the output of ``counter.values()`` and please format your traceback as ``code`` (there is a button for that) but with newlines. And could you provide some (minimal) input for the function so that the error can be verified (see also the [Guideline for Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: @MSeifert edited my question as per your request. I have also added some data from the waypoints.json file. Basicaly i want to plot a graph on speed key in the json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you made an incorrect assumption about what `tuple()` does to a string:

```
tuple("Speed")
# returns ('S', 'p', 'e', 'e', 'd')
```

I think you want:

```
labels = counter.keys()
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. I replaced the line but i got this error. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new.py", line 71, in <module>
    visualize_type(sorted_waypoints)
  File "new.py", line 36, in visualize_type
    labels = x.keys()
NameError: global name 'x' is not defined

Comment: sorry, I've been confused about the variable names. Edited the answer. Must be ``counter.keys()``. Sorry

Comment: ``plt.plot([item["TimeStamp"] for item in output], [item["Speed"] for item in output])`` but this has nothing to do with this question. If you have any further or related questions please open another question, follow the [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then people will help you.